# Every Borel contains a Cartan, and conjugacy theorems: A simple proof?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

### Conjugacy of Borel subalgebras $\newcommand{\ad}{\mathrm{ad}\,}$

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. A Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak{b} \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ is a maximal solvable subalgebra. It is a classic theorem that all Borel subalgebras of semisimple $\mathfrak{g}$ are conjugate under

- the action of $\langle \exp(\ad x): x \in \mathfrak{g} \text{ ad-nilpotent}\rangle$, or
- the adjoint action of an algebraic group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$,

the first sense implying the second. The proof I know of (e.g. in Humphrey's *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*) are very involved, involving a complicated induction on the dimension of intersection of two Borel subalgebras, as well as on the dimension of the ambient Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

### Conjugacy of Cartan subalgebras

In contrast, there is a short, geometric proof that all Cartan subalgebras of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ are conjugate. One uses the following lemma from algebraic geometry:

**Lemma**: If $f: \mathbb{A}^m \to \mathbb{A}^n$ has $df_x$ surjective for some $x \in \mathbb{A}^m$, then the image of $f$ contains a dense open subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Now given a root space decomposition
$$ \mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Phi} \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$$
with root vectors $x_\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$, define $f: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ by
$$ f(h + \sum_{\alpha \in \Phi} t_\alpha x_\alpha) = \left(\prod_{\alpha \in \Phi} \exp (t_\alpha \ad x_\alpha)\right) h,$$
where $h \in \mathfrak{h}$ and the product is taken in some fixed order.
The differential at any regular element of $\mathfrak{h}$ is nonzero, which shows that the conjugates of $\mathfrak{h}$ under the exponentials of nilpotent elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ contains a dense open subset of $\mathfrak{g}$, and thus intersects the conjugates of any other Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h'}$. Further, as regular semisimple elements are dense in $\mathfrak{g}$, every Cartan contains a regular semisimple element and thus is equal to the centralizer of a regular semisimple element.

### Hope for a better life

Further, one can show that if a Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ contains the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h} \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$, then $\mathfrak{b}$ must be one of the "standard" Borel subalgebras associated to $\mathfrak{h}$, formed by taking the sum of $\mathfrak{h}$ with all positive roots (after fixing such a choice of positive roots). The problem of showing that all Borel subalgebras are conjugate thus reduces to showing that every Borel subalgebra contains a Cartan. This leads to the question:

> Is there a geometric argument for that every Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ contains a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, akin to the geometric argument for Cartan subalgebras above?

It would be helpful even to have a geometric argument showing that every Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ contains a regular semisimple element.

Comment: If this were algebraic groups I'd say that a Borel $B$ contains a maximal torus $T$. If it weren't a maximal torus of $G$ I'd take $T'$ a maximal torus of $G$ containing $T$ then $BT'$ would be a larger solvable subgroup which would be a contradiction. Does something like this not work for Lie algebras?

Comment: Joshua, did you see my comment? I'm not claiming it actually solves your question, I'm just legitimately curious.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I did, I haven't had a chance to think about whether it solves the question yet. I'll have some time today.

Comment: No problem. Take your time!

Comment: @AlexYoucis I don't see how to show $BT'$ is solvable: $T'$ may not be normal in $BT'$. I think that $G$ is semisimple must be used in some way for this argument also.

Comment: Ah, you are probably right. I was being silly. The proof then I probably want to say is that a maximal torus $T$ of $G$ is contained in some Borel of $G$ (since $T$ is solvable and connected). Since all Borels are conjugate this implies that every Borel contains a conjugate of $T$ and thus a maximal torus. I guess then you want to know why all Borels are conjugate. If you're working over $\overline{k}$ there is a simple proof because any solvable acting on a proper variety has a fixed point. So, you take $B$ some fixed Borel. You want to show that if $B'$ is another Borel then

Comment: $B'\subseteq gBg^{-1}$ for some $g$. You look at $G/B$ which is proper and let $B'$ act by left multlication. By the above stated result there is some $gB\in G/B$ such that $B'gB=gB$ which says that $B'=gBg^{-1}$. So I guess the geometricd result you are looking for is the Borel fixed point theorem?